# Is there something like a simple "Data Manager" out there?

Tags: content-management-system

i hope my english is not too bad, to explain what iam looking for.

So recently i configured my first gulp/npm project with scss compiler, pug template engine, bootstrap4 and some more.

At this point i only have the option to hardcode "data" or use something like json to implement contents - yes that works.

But what iam looking for is something else...

If i build this type of page is usually use a content management system like contao (or wordpress, typo3 etc.)

But i want to use my cool gulp/npm etc enviroment with that fancy dependencies and complete flexibility AND use just a simple "Dataset" Manager with a really simple Backend for my customers.

I give you a example.

I get a new project, i already have a layout and some days ago i created a cool base for new projects, with configured gulp tasks etc.

the customer wants to show his employees and want to manage them by himself.
at this point its simply not possible.

so i would like to give him access to a database(or not) driven backend where i initially created, i call it "datasets", which he can manage and create new items etc.

in the building process i go to the simple backend, click "new dataset", create 
 a textfield (name for example), a description field and a imagefield and save - to create some dummies and in the template self i do something like a for(datasets['employees']) and build the employee layout.

just a simple "data manager" which i can connect to a template engine of my choice (or a template engine of the datamanagers choice, it doesnt matter).

iam not the biggest coder outthere, iam basically a frontend-developer but THIS could help me so much and iam not depended on a content managemend system anymore.

thank you for your help and iam really excited for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

either you write your own CMS or you adapt your *cool* logic to an existing CMS.
There are so many CMSs with different approaches that you should be able to find one you can adapt or abuse for your need.
Adapting a CMS (write a plugin or extension to the CMS) should be the preferred way as you might benefit from the evolution of the CMS.
If you abuse (use it in a not intended way) you will probably getting problems with time and evolution of the CMS.

Comment: hey bernd, first of all thank your for your answer!
can you recommend me a cms which fits in my described needs?

thanks again for your feedback!

Comment: that depends on your needs. if you want your own logic for the data *and* a std-CMS you need to adapt your logic to the logic of the CMS. As I'm very familiar with TYPO3 I can say: it would be possible with TYPO3 as TYPO3 has a good API to build BE modules (where editors can enter data). and so I know it well I might be able to work aside from TYPO3, but that is no recommendation to do it on a regulary base. In general: try to find a CMS you might get familar (look for CMS which work in your preferred programming language and database) and which has the option to integrate your logic.